# Woocommerce shipping method error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for help with a plugin that needs an additional line of code.

So there are 3 shipping methods.
-First one comes from a plugin that provides with an opportunity to choose a terminal for shipping from a dropdown menu. If terminal from the dropdown menu is not selected an error will be displayed after pressing the pay button. 
-Second ant third shipping methods are almost the same. They are just one button click shipping methods.

The problem is that if I decide to choose second or third shipping method the same error as for first shipping method will be displayed. That is because no terminal is selected from the drop downmenu. On the second and third method dropdown menu disappears as it should be.

This is the code line, that check if a terminal is selected from the dropdown menu.

```
// Checkout validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation',                   
array( $this, 'validate_user_selected_terminal' ), 10, 1 );
```

I need help adding if or other statement that this error would only be displayed for the first shipping method.

GitHub of the file: https://github.com/zefy/lp-express-shipping-method-for-woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-lpexpress-terminals-shipping-method.php

```
// Meta and input field name
$this->id  = 'lpexpress_terminals';
```

Really need to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am creator of this plugin and this issue has been resolved. Please check GitHub repository again or just update your plugin.